# Why my calculator doesn't appear in console

Tags: python

I was writing a calculator which:

- should calculate
- ask if I want to continue with the score
- clear console if not.

Since I added def calculator console is empty.

What did I do?

```
def add(n1, n2):
    return n1 + n2

def subtract(n1, n2):
    return n1 - n2

def divide(n1, n2):
    return n1 / n2

def multiply(n1, n2):
    return n1 * n2

symbols = {
    "+" : add,
    "-" : subtract,
    "/" : divide,
    "*" : multiply,
}

def calculator():
    
    num1 = int(input("What is your first number:"))
    
    should_continue = True

    while should_continue:
        for symbol in symbols:
            print(symbol)

        sign = input("What kind of operation do you choose: ")

        num2 = int(input("What is your next number: "))

        calculation_function = symbols[sign]
        score = calculation_function(num1, num2)

        print ( f"Your score is: {score}.")

        continue_calc = input("Do you want to continue with the score: 'y' or 'n'? ")
        if continue_calc == 'y':
            shold_continue = True
            num1 = score
        else:
            should_continue = False
            print("Thank you for using calculator.")
            calculator()
```

Thank you also for hints on how to improve my code.

Greetings :)

Comment: Do do not call `calculator`?

Comment: you don't call the `calculator()` function...  (only inside the function itself - but that is not where you want to call it..); move the last line to the very left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling your calculator function because its within your calculator function. Remember python needs proper formating.

Should be:

```
def calculator():
    
    num1 = int(input("What is your first number:"))
    
    should_continue = True

    while should_continue:
        for symbol in symbols:
            print(symbol)

        sign = input("What kind of operation do you choose: ")

        num2 = int(input("What is your next number: "))

        calculation_function = symbols[sign]
        score = calculation_function(num1, num2)

        print ( f"Your score is: {score}.")

        continue_calc = input("Do you want to continue with the score: 'y' or 'n'? ")
        if continue_calc == 'y':
            shold_continue = True
            num1 = score
        else:
            should_continue = False
            print("Thank you for using calculator.")
                
calculator()
```

Comment: also, it is good practice to put the main code inside a if __name__ == "__main__": block to prevent it to execute when the mentioned code is part of a module.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about this easy thing.